# How to code logarithm in python(without any libraries)

Tags: python

Yes, I know that you can do:

```
import math

print(math.log(2, 10))
```

But I want to do it without using any libraries. Is it even possible?

I could try using:

```
def log(a, base):
  for x in range(0, base):
    if base ** x == round(a, 5):
      return x
```

but that would be slow.

Comment: You can approximate natural logarithm with [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61211

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function:

```
def log(a, base):
    x = 0
    while a >= base:
        a /= base
        x += 1
    return x
```

Comment: This assumes that the result is integral, not really in line with [math.log](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below.
This differs from the previous one by continuous calculation.
The parameter settings will affect the calculation speed.

```
def log(a, base):
    if base <= 1 or a <= 0:
        return None
    elif base == a:
        return 1 
    elif a == 1:
        return 0 
    else:
        lower, upper = 0, a
        while upper - lower > 1e-10:  # some small number
            mid = (lower + upper) / 2
            if base ** mid < a:
                lower = mid
            else:
                upper = mid
        return round(lower, 10)  # accuracy
```